# Background color change from dropdown using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to be able to change background colour by having to choose from drop down menu.

```
<div id="background">
                <p><b>Choose a colour to change<br> background colour from the list.</b></p>
                    <select name="colour" id="background-change">
                        <option>Select One</option>
                        <option>Black</option> 
                        <option>Blue</option>
                        <option>Orange</option> 
                        <option>Red</option>
                        <option>White</option>
                        <option>Yellow</option>
                    </select> 
</div>
```

Thats my HTML drop down code and the colours i need the background to change. Also I would like to have it save in the cookie so if i pick red and refresh the page, it would still be red.

Comment: I know basic Javascript and i would like some hints or someone to get me started.

Comment: Do you know how to change a background color in HTML5?

Comment: Bind `onchange` to your select element. Add values to your options. Apply style to body (or class) based on value. Fiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/yfp0zm8t/

Comment: @JackPattishall maybe post it as an answer and i'll vote it as an answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//$("#background").css("background-color",$.cookie("defaultColor"));

    $("#background-change").change(function (event) {
      var color =  $(this).val();
       $("#background").css("background-color",color);

        //$.cookie("defaultColor",color);
    });
});
```

The code will change the background based on the selected value in the dropdown list.

To set and retrieve cookie using jQuery, you have to use the **[jQuery Cookie Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)**

Use this code to set cookie

```
$.cookie("defaultColor",color);
```

Then use this code to retrieve cookie and set it as the backround color

```
$("#background").css("background-color",$.cookie("defaultColor"));
```

Check the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubdcown4/1/)**

Comment: I downloaded it and unzipped it. What i did is copy and paste the file "jquery.cookie.js" and added '<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>' in my HTML and doesnt work, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Pls refer to this link https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie for instructions